# a question about solidity msg.data

Tags: solidity

my solidity code is below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {

    event Event(address);
    event TestEvent(uint256);
    event Data(bytes);
    event Data1(bytes);
    function show() public returns(uint256){
        emit Event(msg.sender);
        return 100;
    }

    function test(uint256 a)external returns(bytes){

        emit Data(msg.data);
        emit TestEvent(a);
        return msg.data;

    }
    function caller1(address _addr) {
        emit Data1(abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256("test(uint256)")),100));
        _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256("test(uint256)")),100));
    }
}

contract Call {

    function caller1(address _addr) {
        _addr.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256("test(uint256)")),100));
    }
}
```

I have been deployed contract Test and Call。when I call function test(100) directly, this event Data show the msg.data is "0x29e99f070000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064",ok.

But, when I call the contract Test's function caller1 or contract Call's function caller1 to call the function test by solidity lib function .call,the event Data show the msg.data is "0x29e99f07000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".

yes,you can see this msg.data is longer than that one ,this msg.data is much more an  hexString "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000".the length of the hexString is 56,of course,the length is 26 byte.
Why,somebody could you help me .

My English is poorly,understand what I say ?

Comment: Something is wrong with how you are calling the function. When you say you are calling `caller1`, you should have a different value at the front of the function call. `29e99f07` should be specific to the function you are calling, so it has to represent either `test` or `caller1`, but not both

Answer (score 1):

**This has been fixed** and works properly starting with the first **0.4.26** nightly build ( 0.4.26-nightly.2018.9.13+commit.8b089cc8 )

Trying to use it in a version prior to this will most likely result in issues:

I can reproduce the issue you found and it seems to be an oversight in the abi.encodeWithSelector method that adds an extra 28 bytes to the result.

These typically **get ignored** when read by the called method.

BUT can cause issues if ignored and used in this form in checks like ( some token transfer payload size checks )

```
modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint numwords) {
    assert(msg.data.length == numwords * 32 + 4);
_;
```

### **How the ABI works:**

The solidity v1 ABI uses 32byte words to pad / store variables.

**msg.data** starts with 4 bytes that represent the first 4 bytes of the hash of the method you're calling

add 32 bytes for each of the arguments you're passing, which depending on the type are as follow:

- a) 32 bytes value if simple type like uint / byte / bytes[1-32] / bool / etc
- b) 32 bytes containing the pointer to the address where the variable content starts in the msg.data in case of dynamic size variables ( strings / arrays )

  - Pointer then leads to a 32 byte space where we find the number of words / 32 byte blocks used by our variable then based on said number we know how many blocks to read to get the full contents

### **Fallback:**

If you do want to call it "properly" you can use the good old tested way

```
_address.call(bytes4(bytes32(keccak256("_method(type1,typeN)"))), _param, _paramN));
```

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: Feel free to accept the question if it does the job for you, thanks.